# Jquery not being enqueued properly in Wordpress theme

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress-theming, slicknav

I'm building my first ever Wordpress theme & I'm trying to implement some plugins. I'm an absolute beginner, so please excuse my total lack of knowledge with it!

As far as I am aware, you need to enqueue scripts in the functions.php file for JQuery to work. I have done this, but by following an array of different tutorials / with the advice of my tutor. It seems that it still will not work & I don't know what to do from here!

I'm sure to the trained eye, it will be perfectly obvious where I've gone wrong & that's fine, because it's exactly what I need! :)

Here's the code from my functions.php file:

```
            <?php

            function my_init() {
                if (!is_admin()) {

                wp_register_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js', false, '1.11.0', true);
                wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

                wp_register_script('scrollup', get_template_directory_uri() . '/scrollup-master/js/jquery.scrollUp.min.js', array('jquery', 'jquery-ui-core'), '1.11.0', true );

                wp_enqueue_script('jquery.scrollUp');

                wp_register_script('slicknav', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.slicknav.min.js', array('jquery', 'jquery-ui-core'), '1.11.0', true );

                wp_enqueue_script('slicknav');
                }
            }
            add_action('init', 'my_init');

            // Add action to load scripts enqued in load_scripts() function
            add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_scripts');


            ?>
```

And here is the script I've put into the footer.php file:

```
            <script>
              $.scrollUp({
                scrollName: 'scrollUp', // Element ID
                topDistance: '300', // Distance from top before showing element (px)
                topSpeed: 300, // Speed back to top (ms)
                animation: 'fade', // Fade, slide, none
                animationInSpeed: 200, // Animation in speed (ms)
                animationOutSpeed: 200, // Animation out speed (ms)
                scrollText: 'Scroll to top', // Text for element
                activeOverlay: false, // Set CSS color to display scrollUp active point, e.g '#00FFFF'
              });
            });
            </script>

            <script>
                $(function(){
                    $('#menu').slicknav();
                });
            </script>
```

Any help would be massively appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Wordpress enques jQuery by default if I'm not mistaken.
What happens when you check the source of your live code and follow the path to jquery shown in your header there?

Answer (score 1):

You should never register your own version of jquery, it is included in wordpress core.

Please read and understand the codex page for [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).

You should only register scripts not in core, and use the dependency argument of `wp_enqueue_script` to make sure jquery is available.

Your code doesn't make much sense, scripts should be enqueued at `wp_enqueue_scripts` rather than `init` and I'm not sure why you included an admin hook?

```
function yasmin_enqueue_scripts()
{
     wp_enqueue_script( /* ... */ );

     //...
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'yasmin_enqueue_scripts' );
```

---

Your javascript should not go in footer.php, it should be in a separate file and loaded with `wp_enqueue_script`. It should also be wrapped in a non-conflict wrapper (self executing function)

```
(function($){
    // all jquery code goes in here
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: As I said, I'm brand new to this, so I don't necessarily understand the code I'm working with here! Apologies again! Could you please expand on the separate javascript file?

Comment: Your javascript should not go in footer.php, it should be enqueued in the same way as you have done for e.g slicknav. Put the javascript in a new file somewhere in your theme folder and include it using `wp_enqueue_script` with its dependencies as jquery, slicknav, etc

Comment: I'm still having no luck I'm afraid. Thanks for trying to help though.

Comment: Are you using a child theme? If so try replacing `get_template_directory_uri` with `get_stylesheet_directory_uri`.

Comment: If you have never done this before try enqueue-ing a simple script that does something like `alert('ok');` and see if you can get that going.

Comment: No it's a theme I've built from scratch. Basically I was briefed to make a website for an organisation that my tutor runs. So I made a static site, but he then decided that instead of just a static HTML site, he wanted me to build a Wordpress theme & pull the content for it from a Wordpress that he has already set up. So as a static coder, I'm really out of my comfort zone coding in this way. The theme itself looks & works fine, it's just including the scripts that I can't get my head around.

Answer (score 0):

To load jquery or other js file you can edit the function on this way

```
       <?php

        function my_init() {

            wp_register_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js', false, '1.11.0', true);
            wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

            wp_register_script('scrollup', get_template_directory_uri() . '/scrollup-master/js/jquery.scrollUp.min.js', array('jquery', 'jquery-ui-core'), '1.11.0', true );

            wp_enqueue_script('jquery.scrollUp');

            wp_register_script('slicknav', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.slicknav.min.js', array('jquery', 'jquery-ui-core'), '1.11.0', true );

            wp_enqueue_script('slicknav');

        }
       if (!is_admin()){
       add_action( 'wp_enqueue_script', 'my_init' );
      }


        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently, Wordpress provide [jQuery with noConflict Wrapper](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers).

Try to use the code with `jQuery` like below:

```
<script>
  (function($) {
    $.scrollUp({
      scrollName: 'scrollUp', // Element ID
      topDistance: '300', // Distance from top before showing element (px)
      topSpeed: 300, // Speed back to top (ms)
      animation: 'fade', // Fade, slide, none
      animationInSpeed: 200, // Animation in speed (ms)
      animationOutSpeed: 200, // Animation out speed (ms)
      scrollText: 'Scroll to top', // Text for element
      activeOverlay: false, // Set CSS color to display scrollUp active point, e.g '#00FFFF'
    });
  })(jQuery);
</script>
```